# Google App engine - External image/video counts bandwidth?

Tags: google-app-engine

In Google App Engine free 1GB bandwidth hosting website if we have  external image and videos like youtube will this external video/image be counted in the given 1GB bandwidth? Please clarify. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason why *externally hosted* images and YouTube videos would count towards your App Engine bandwidth -- they are loaded from an **external** source afterall.

Answer (score 0):

No, they do not count as pointed by Marvin Pinto. Instead, it's recommended you use external services for serving your static media/content as it will allows your application to server more dynamic content.